# Not able to detect failed testcase

Tags: c#, selenium, automation, nunit

I am creating a testcases which runs via Selenium and nunit. While running my testcases I get screeshot of my screen at the end with the help of text context if test case passed then image should move to Pass folder else to fail. But what exactly hapening is, it only detects Passed testcases which is else statement in my code snippet. What am I missing as it does not detect failed test teststatus

```
[Test]
public void TestCase_55215()
{
 ... Specific TestCase Function
 string Name = methodBase.Name;
 GetResult(Name); // Moves all screenshot to specific folder (Pass or Fail Folder) after running the test case function test on nunit
}

    public void GetResult(string testName)
    {
          if (TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.Status == TestStatus.Failed)
                        {
                            string sourcepath = @"source";
                            string destpath = (@"Destination\" + TestCase - " + testName);
                            Directory.CreateDirectory(destpath);
                            string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles((sourcepath), "*.png");
                            Parallel.ForEach(files, file =>
                            {
                                System.IO.File.Move(file, System.IO.Path.Combine(destpath, System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file)));

                            });

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            string sourcepath = @"sourcepath";
                            string destpath = @"Destination";
                            Directory.CreateDirectory(destpath);
                            string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles((sourcepath), "*.png");
                            Parallel.ForEach(files, file =>
                            {
                                System.IO.File.Move(file, System.IO.Path.Combine(destpath, System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file)));

                            });
                         }
```

As per my code,

Expected Result:  Should move images to Fail folder

Actual Result:  screenshot images are saves in parent folder non Folder name.

Comment: You don't say exactly what you are doing, but possibly an exception is thrown when it failed, so your code is not run any more.

Comment: Please check my description. And if you stil didn't understood please ask question on what part you didn't understood.

Comment: Where is your assertions? NUnit will throws AssertionException after it execute the assertion statement. If you don't try/catch it, your GetResults() method won't be reached. Moreover, you have to call GetResults() inside TearDown method instead of Test method.

Comment: I am using outside because I am having argument in test method. Please check my code.

Comment: Do you try/catch the AssertionException yet?

Answer (score 0):

NUnit sets the result in the context after the test finishes. Your call to GetResult is part of the test. At that point, since it hasn't finished, there is no meaningful result.

If you want to access the result in a useful way, do it in a Teardown method.

Answer (score 0):

You have to catch exceptions from NUnit. See code below:

```
string Name = methodBase.Name;            
try
{
    // Specific TestCase Function
    Assert.Fail("This is a fail test");
}
catch (SuccessException ex)
{
    // Test passed
    GetResult(Name);
}
catch (AssertionException exception)
{
    // Test failed
    GetResult(Name);
}
catch (Exception exception)
{
    // Test Inconclusive or Error occurs
    GetResult(Name);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If it only detects else part, it means that `Result.Status` is always at false... Double check where you set it before calling your method.

Comment: I didn't set `Result.Status` as false in entire solution.

Comment: I assume that `TestStatus.Failed` is a boolean (true/false).
So if you are not setting `TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.Status` no where, why are you checking it against `TestStatus.Failed`

Comment: So how is the solution to detect that test case failed.

Comment: Not sure what is going on in your code, can you paste it somewhere.

Comment: I have explained what I am doing with `TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.Status`  before my code. Have read that? If yes you would have understood if you have used Result.Status

Comment: I have updated my description to make it more understandable.

Comment: `TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.Status` must be set to true or false somewhere. Try right clicking on `Result.Status` and click _find usages_

Comment: One question: Have you ever done automation scripting or used this TestContext?